# Linear ODE with one periodic coefficient

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, fundamental-solution

I'm interested in the following equation

$$\ddot{f} - \cos^2(\omega t) \dot{f} - f = 0$$

with an initial condition $f(0) = f_0$. I don't think there is a closed-form solution, but do you know if this equation has been studied somewhere, or where I should look about it?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you checked what happens for various $h$ that satisfy the criteria?

Comment: $\cos(\omega t) < 0$ for $t \in (\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$

Comment: You have a linear (time-varying) dynamical system of the form $\dot{\mathbf x} = \mathbf A (t) \, \mathbf x$. The challenge is to find the [state transition matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix). I have seen cases where $\mathbf A (t)$ is periodic. More at [Antsaklis & Michel](https://books.google.com/books?id=Irr0W8s4rKUC).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $r=\tan \omega t$ ,

Then $\dfrac{df}{dt}=\dfrac{df}{dr}\dfrac{dr}{dt}=\omega(\sec^2\omega t)\dfrac{df}{dr}$

$\dfrac{d^2f}{dt^2}=\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\omega(\sec^2\omega t)\dfrac{df}{dr}\right)=\omega(\sec^2\omega t)\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{df}{dr}\right)+2\omega^2(\sec^2\omega t\tan \omega t)\dfrac{df}{dr}=\omega(\sec^2\omega t)\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(\dfrac{df}{dr}\right)\dfrac{dr}{dt}+2\omega^2(\sec^2\omega t\tan \omega t)\dfrac{df}{dr}=\omega(\sec^2\omega t)\dfrac{d^2f}{dr^2}\omega(\sec^2\omega t)+2\omega^2(\sec^2\omega t\tan \omega t)\dfrac{df}{dr}=\omega^2(\sec^4\omega t)\dfrac{d^2f}{dr^2}+2\omega^2(\sec^2\omega t\tan \omega t)\dfrac{df}{dr}$

$\therefore\omega^2(\sec^4\omega t)\dfrac{d^2f}{dr^2}+2\omega^2(\sec^2\omega t\tan \omega t)\dfrac{df}{dr}-\omega\dfrac{df}{dr}-f=0$

$\omega^2(r^2+1)^2\dfrac{d^2f}{dr^2}+(2\omega^2r(r^2+1)-\omega)\dfrac{df}{dr}-f=0$

$\dfrac{d^2f}{dr^2}+\left(\dfrac{2r}{r^2+1}-\dfrac{1}{\omega(r^2+1)^2}\right)\dfrac{df}{dr}-\dfrac{f}{\omega^2(r^2+1)^2}=0$

Comment: Nice. Is this because you've seen this before? Or is there a way to determine by inspection if a differential equation is algebraic up to transcendental change of coordinates?